# Android AVD is crashing with NullPointerException on startup

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to set up an Android Virtual Device (AVD) on my Debian Wheezy machine. I run this command, and the AVD Manager opened like it should:

```
/.../android-sdk/tools/android avd
```

Then, I tried to add an AVD for an existing device, but it just didn't start up, without any error message. So I created my own device and an AVD for it, and it starts up, but just shows the Android splash screen without any changes for hours. I read through the LogCat (`adb logcat`) and found this error message being repeated about every minute:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1672): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: WindowManager
E/AndroidRuntime( 1672): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 1672):        at com.android.server.display.LocalDisplayAdapter$LocalDisplayDevice.getDisplayDeviceInfoLocked(LocalDisplayAdapter.java:147)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1672):        at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService.handleDisplayDeviceAddedLocked(DisplayManagerService.java:852)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1672):        at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService.handleDisplayDeviceAdded(DisplayManagerService.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1672):        at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService.access$1100(DisplayManagerService.java:96)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1672):        at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService$DisplayAdapterListener.onDisplayDeviceEvent(DisplayManagerService.java:1281)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1672):        at com.android.server.display.DisplayAdapter$1.run(DisplayAdapter.java:108)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1672):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1672):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1672):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1672):        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1672): Error reporting crash
E/AndroidRuntime( 1672): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 1672):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:84)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1672):        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1672):        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

I also tried to delete the `$HOME/.android/avd` folder and recreating the AVD, but it didn't help.

How can I fix this error? Note that I only have installed the SDK, not Eclipse.

Comment: Did you run the command android to run the sdk manager and update the tools and sdks? Did you take the following steps on https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools > click on instructions for all platforms > and then click on Ubuntu troubleshooting. I couldn't find a more direct link, sorry.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk It seems like I was missing the `ia32-lib` package, but after installing it and restarting all android processes the AVD even doesn't open, and not connecting to adb (so no error messages are available)

Comment: Which Java do you have installed? Updating the environment variables and restarting your terminal window may help too. After that, are you able to start your sdk manager by running android and are you able to update your sdks/build tools through the sdk manager?

Comment: I have OpenJDK7 and OrakleJDK8 installed with OrakleJDK8 in my path variable

Comment: OpenJDK won't work for Android. OracleJDK8 should work because it's supposed to be backward-compatible. But officially, only OracleJDK6 and OracleJDK7 are officially supported and recommended for Android. That being said, I doubt that's the issue. What about the sdk manager? are you able to launch it by using the command android? Also, by updating the environment variables, I meant doing this: export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I'm able to start the SDK Manager. I have the PATH variable exported correctly. Exporting the ANDROID_HOME variable too didn't help, same Exception